# How can I get in groovy a single value in an array structure

Tags: jenkins-groovy

my English is not the best but I will try it :o)

I have a problem with groovy in a Jenkins Pipeline file.

I will show my code a little bit different to my code so that it is not so complicated to understand but it has the same meaning.

I have defined a 2D array like this:

```
def address=[
                1: [NAME:'PAUL', 
                            Telephone: [
                                1: [number: '1234', id:'office'],
                                2: [number: '2345', id:'mobile'],
                                3: [number: '4567', id:'home'],
                                ]],
                2: [NAME:'PETER', 
                            Telephone: [
                                1: [number: '9876', id:'office'],
                                2: [number: '7654', id:'mobile'],
                                3: [number: '5432', id:'home'],
                                ]],
                3: [NAME:'MICHAEL', 
                            Telephone: [
                                1: [number: '5647', id:'office'],
                                2: [number: '4738', id:'mobile'],
                                3: [number: '2954', id:'home'],
                                ]],                                                                
]
```

Then I have somewhere a function like this.

```
def showNumbers(address){
    address.each{entry ->
        name=entry.value.NAME
        echo 'Name: '+name
        // prints out the whole 2D array
        echo "Print Out 1 = ${entry}"
        // prints out only the name
        echo "Print Out 2 = ${entry.value.NAME}"
        // prints out the Telephone array
        echo "Print Out 3 = ${entry.value.Telephone}"

        // now I want to save only the first number "1234" to do later something with it...
        save_first_number=?????

        // print out the number array
        entry.value.Devices.each{telephone ->
            echo 'Number from: '+name
            echo 'Number: '+telephone.value.number + ' - ID: '+telephone.value.id


        }// End of => entry.value.Devices.each{entry ->
    }// End of => array.each{entry ->
}
```

BTW:
I know that this address array makes no sense in Jenkins but as I told, it is just an example how it is in my code!!

So my problem is, that I don't know how I get only the first single value from “number” in the first entry [1:] I need only the value ‘1234’ and then, when I go to the next iteration, I want to have from peter the number “9876” and so one.

My thought is something like this...

```
save_first_number = entry.value.Telephone[1].value.number
```

But that doesn’t work.

I hope it is clear what I mean :o)
I hope also that someone can please help me in this case.

Best regards and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since entry.value.Telephone[1] is a HashMap, u can access its element like this :

```
save_first_number = entry.value.Telephone[1]['number']
save_first_number = entry.value.Telephone[1].number // works as well

// to check types:
// println "${entry.value.Telephone[1].getClass()}" // returns LinkedHashMap
```

Comment: Hello chenchuk,

yes that it!!
Now it runs.
I don’t know why I did not came to it by myself. It looks so clear now.
Thanks a lot for your help an best regards :o)

Comment: please accept the answer if you find it useful, thanks .